# How to fix 'name 'cross_validation' is not defined' error in python

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, xgbclassifier

I am trying to run XGBClassifier parameter tuning and get a "'name 'cross_validation' is not defined" error following this line of code:

```py
  kfold_5 =  cross_validation.KFold(n = len(X), shuffle = True, n_folds = numFolds)
```

Maybe I didn't import the appropriate library?

Comment: let me know if my answer helps

Comment: @serafeim great answer worked perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get your version:

```
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
```

After scikit-learn version 0.17, the `cross_validation.KFold` has been migrated to `model_selection.KFold`.

**If you have the 0.17 version, use this:**

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold

kfold_5 = KFold(n= len(X), n_folds = numFolds, shuffle=True)
```

**If you have a version newer than 0.17, use this:**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

kfold_5 = KFold(n_splits = numFolds, shuffle=True)
```

[Documentation for 0.21 version is here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html)

Comment: The import statement depends on the OP's sklearn version. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Indeed it is - (+1) now (previous versions of the answer assumed that OP had a new version, while such info is not provided)

Comment: @serafeim For  the  first code snippet I get "No module named 'sklearn.cross_validation'
For the 2nd  I get "TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n'"

Comment: for the second, did you type exactly `kfold_5 = KFold(n_splits = numFolds, shuffle=True)` ? The input arguments are not the same as in the first case, in this case.

Comment: @ErezBen-Moshe please pay close attention to the provided snippets; in the 2nd snippet there should **not** be any argument `n`